# how to process and load data after rendering a page in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a dashboard page with some charts([image_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uamvO.png))

For earning charts data, i'm using some queries but this queries are very heavy and take long time(for example 37 seconds!).

Is exist a way for rendering page(with showing loading animation on charts) and after that start taking data process?

Comment: Are you aware of `AJAX`?

Comment: no, i dont used it

Comment: You can use `AJAX` to make requests after the page loads or on different events.

Comment: I don't know ajax, is there a way for doing this work with python or django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django is for logic, what you need is frontend skills.

If you learned one of 'React, Vue, Angular',

it would be very easy to implement loading animation to your application.

unfortunately, there is no way for the loader in any backend framework

include django.